# Javascript regex with word boundary includes word with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a word boundary \b check for matching words that also work if there are certain special characters in the word getting matched, such as Ø, but preferably not characters like ! or ?. Since the special character is at the end of the word, the \b sees it as being "open space" and therefore matches the word without it actually being a free-standing word. 
Is this possible to do? 
Right now this check matches both words, but i would like it to only match the word with "Ford".

```js
const nodes = [{
  textContent: "Ford is the best"
}, {
  textContent: "Fordørgen is the best"
}];

const variable = 'Ford';
const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + variable + '\\b');

const matches = nodes.filter(function(node) {
    return regex.test(node.textContent);
});

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Try: `const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + variable + '(?!\\S)');`

Comment: @anubhava this also seems to work, so now im left to wonder if there's a performance difference between these two solutions, or if it really matters which one i choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` only works for ascii, you have to use unicode properties to handle non-ascii word boundaries, for example:

```js
const nodes = [{
  textContent: "Ford is the best"
}, {
  textContent: "Fordørgen is the best"
}];

const variable = 'Ford';
const regex = new RegExp('(?<!\\p{Alpha})' + variable + '(?!\\p{Alpha})', 'u');

const matches = nodes.filter(function(node) {
    return regex.test(node.textContent);
});

console.log(matches);
```

`(?<!\\p{Alpha}) xxx (?!\\p{Alpha})` means `xxx`, unless preceded or followed by a unicode alphabetic character.

Docs: [Unicode Property Escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes)

Comment: This looks like exactly what i needed, thanks a lot. I'll accept the answer once i am able to. Do you know if there's any difference in performance between the '\\b' + variable + '(?!\\S)' and this kind of Regex?

Comment: @Reaver: I don't know, but I doubt this part is going to be a bottleneck in your program.